# Proper syntax for raising an error that a function returns

Tags: vba, ms-access

This function returns either an error number, or 0 if it ran smoothly.

```
Public Function DeleteTable(tblName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tblName
    DeleteTable = Err
End Function
```

This sub works fine...

```
Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
    Dim ReturnedErr As Long
    ReturnedErr = DeleteTable("tblFoo")
    If ReturnedErr Then Err.Raise ReturnedErr

    'do stuff
End Sub
```

But is there a way to write it where I don't have to pass the returned value into a new variable? Seems clunky. Is something like this possible?

```
Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
    err.raise DeleteTable("tblFoo")
    '(doesn't work because an err.raise of 0 ... raises an error)

    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: You could just let the error bubble up from `DeleteTable` ?

Comment: It could just be a sub and have it display result instead of passing back to calling procedure. Why raise a run-time error as opposed to handling error that is generated? http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteTable(tblName As String) ' a Sub is just fine
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Raise 1 ' <- just for testing: any error, other than 0
End Sub
Public Sub test()
    DeleteTable ("tblFoo") ' <- don't return the err.number in DeleteTable
    If Err.Number Then     ' <- the error of the last statement will be preserved
       'Err.Raise Err.Number ' <- You can raise the error now, it is always a valid error number here
       'Or show a better message than MS does:
       MsgBox "Error(" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "in '" & Mid(Application.CodeDb.Name,1+InstrRev(Application.CodeDb.Name,"\")) & "', Function 'DeleteTable'"
    Else
       'do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. I knew I was overthinking things haha.
For what its worth, I was using an `On Error GoTo` statement in the DeleteTable function instead of `On Error Resume Next`. The Err wasn't being carried back to the parent Sub because of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In such situations it can be helpful to use a Try function as described for VBA in a Rubberduck blog.

https://rubberduckvba.blog/2019/05/09/pattern-tryparse/

A try function returns a boolean (true/False) to indicate if the operation was a success or not.  The desired value and error numbers are returned through ByRef parameters.

The try function should contain only the code that attempts an operation then returns the result of the operation

```
' The DeleteTable method becomes
Public Function TryDeleteTable(byref tblName As String, byref outErrNum as long) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tblName
    outErrnum = err.number
    DeleteTable = Err.number = 0
    on error goto 0
End Function

' and is used as follows

Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
    Dim ReturnedErr As Long
    if Not DeleteTable("tblFoo",ReturnedErr) then
       'deal with error
       'e.g. Err.Raise ReturnedErr
    end if
    ' continue on the happy path

End Sub
```

If you haven't already installed the free and fantastic Rubberduck add in you should do so now.  Its a really really useful addin.

Comment: I'll have to check out the add-in, but this approach looks even clunkier than what I'm working with now.  What's the benefit of using a boolean AND a long for error detection when you can just use the long?

Comment: In the example provided the error is returned to show how to pass back a value.  Typically you wouldn't bother with the error because the function returns true or false. 
 In place of the error you'd know the value returned through the out parameter would be safe to use.  e.g. a valid document reference if you were trying to open a document on a remote server.  If you read the linked article you'd understand better.

Comment: Just finished the article, but I'm still confused - if the function doesn't need to return anything, why use two variables when you only need to use one?

`TryDeleteTable(byref tblName As String) As Long`

Return Err.Number and then use that as a pseudo-boolean when calling the code like so:
`if TryDeleteTable("tblFoo") then 'handle error`

Comment: Ah well.  You can lead a horse to water........